# How to install a specific version of a Sensu plugin using `sensu-install`?

Tags: sensu

In order to prevent that the latest version of a plugin will break the Production monitoring it should be possible to install a specific version:

**Attempt**

```
[user@host ~]$ sensu-install --help
Usage: sensu-install [options]
    -h, --help                       Display this message
    -v, --verbose                    Enable verbose logging
    -p, --plugin PLUGIN              Install a Sensu PLUGIN
    -P, --plugins PLUGIN[,PLUGIN]    PLUGIN or comma-delimited list of Sensu plugins to install
    -s, --source SOURCE              Install Sensu plugins from a custom SOURCE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specify a `plugin version` while installing using `sensu-install`, e.g:

```
sensu-install -p sensu-plugins-disk-checks:2.0.1
```

Or if you want to install multiple plugins with version (note capital -P)

```
sensu-install -P sensu-plugins-disk-checks:2.0.1,sensu-plugins-memory-checks:1.0.2
```

Reference: [#use-sensu-install-to-install-sensu-plugins](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/plugins#use-sensu-install-to-install-sensu-plugins)